# Recognize which of NSTextFields is editing now swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nstextfield

I have to write a program that navigates between multiple NSTextFields (that I store in the array) with keyboard arrows and I need to recognize, which of many NSTextFields user is editing at the moment of test. Is there any way to do that in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NSWindow [firstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/firstResponder) to know which NSTextField is selected at any moment.